# node-red - Installation stuck at gyp for bcrypt

Tags: node.js, node-red, node-gyp

I am running the following commands to install `node-red` on a AWS EC2 `t2.micro` instance.

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
sudo npm install -g node-red`

The installation seems to be in an infinite loop at this point:

`gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp/8.11.1"`

If I hit `Ctrl-C` and rerun `sudo npm install -g node-red` then the installation seems to go through successfully. Is this valid behavior?

Comment: Down-voted? Why?

Comment: compiling native bcrypt can take a LONG TIME, how long did you leave it?

Comment: Over 15 minutes. And, might I suggest updating the documentation on Node-RED installation about `bcrypt` compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing with the `--unsafe-perm` flag.